# Running a script in a google live form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to hide fields or make fields not required depending on the contents of a field when filling the live form?
For example, I have a form with these fields:

- name

  author

  type (multiple choice of either "book" or "comic")

  start date

  end date

  summary

Initially, all fields are visible and marked as required. If the user selects "comic" when filling the live form, I want to hide "end date" field and make summary not required. 
I saw that it's possible to run scripts in google forms, but only when I am editing the form, not when the live form is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: In Google Forms? No

Long Answer: You can if you use [Google Apps Scripting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and the UiApp to custom create a form that can interact if you utilize the [ChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box#addChangeHandler(Handler)) for the [listbox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box).

Cheers.